# When I run my Qt messaging application it stops with exit code -1073741515

Tags: qt

**main:**

```
#include "QtGui/QApplication"
#include "spc_login.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    SPC_LOGIN w;
    //#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
    //    w.showFullScreen();
    //#else
    //    w.show();
    //#endif
    w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**..other code:**

```
protected:
    void changeEvent(QEvent *e);

    private:
        // QAction *softKeyAction;
        // QAction *leftSoftKeyAction;
        Ui::THREESPC_VERIFYINGNUMBER *ui;
        QHttp *getSinHttp;
        QHttp *getOutboundSMSHttp;
        QHttp *putStatusHttp;

        QXmlStreamReader xmlGetSinReader;
        QXmlStreamReader xmlCallOutboundReader;
        QXmlStreamReader xmlPutStatusReader;
        QTimer timer;
        QMessageId sendId;
        QMessageManager manager;
        QMessageService service;
```

When I comment out `QMessageId` and `QMessageManager` varibales then it works fine but when I uncomment these fields, it doesn't work and shows me the exit code `-1073741515`. Please help me.

```
Starting C:\NokiaQtSDK\QtCreator\bin\SPCWIDGET-build-simulator\debug\SPCWIDGET.exe...
C:\NokiaQtSDK\QtCreator\bin\SPCWIDGET-build-simulator\debug\SPCWIDGET.exe exited with code -1073741515
```

Comment: Could you show us your `main()`. What are you returning ?

Comment: #include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "spc_login.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    SPC_LOGIN w;
//#if defined(Q_WS_S60)
//    w.showFullScreen();
//#else
//    w.show();
//#endif
     w.showMaximized();
    return a.exec();
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Installation guide of QtMobility](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/installation.html) about the Messaging module:

> While not supported for this release the desktop Windows backend requires that a MAPI subsystem is installed. Note that messaging functionality will not work if you are using the MinGW compiler. Additionally note that CE MAPI is available on Windows Mobile and does not need to be installed separately.

Which means that you cannot run your application on the desktop. You will have to use an emulator or you have to deploy your app to a device.